# How to add a window in wxpython other then parent frame and use information in sqlite query

Tags: sqlite, user-interface, dialog, wxpython, frame

I have a button in my parent frame(named as Add). I want to open a TextEntryDialog when user clicks that button,I want to open it like a pop up window.And i have to send that text typed by user back to parent frame, which i am going insert into my database table. It would be better if i can make a editable listctrl, in which i will have 4 columns and user will fill information into those columns and by sqlite query i will fill that information into database table.So how can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First tutorial on the first page of a search for "wxpython text dialog"

https://pythonspot.com/en/wxpython-input-dialog/
You don't appear to have put in any effort whatsoever!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import wx

def onButton(event):
    print "Button pressed."

app = wx.App()

frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'win.py')
frame.SetDimensions(0,0,200,50)

# Create text input
dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(frame, 'Enter some text','Text Entry')
dlg.SetValue("Default")
if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
    print('You entered: %s\n' % dlg.GetValue())
dlg.Destroy()
```

Comment: Thanks . I didn't search it with proper keywords.

Comment: If i want to get multiple inputs from user ? i have asked another question for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44773414/on-button-click-open-wxpython-textentrydialog-and-get-multiple-input-from-user                can you please help me there?