# On button click open wxpython TextEntryDialog and get multiple input from user

Tags: python, user-interface, input, dialog, wxpython

I want to open a TextEntryDialog, when user clicks the button. So if i have a button in the parent frame which i am going to bind this way:

```
      self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnAddNew, self.add_new_btn)
```

Now i have to open a TextEntryDialog when user clicks the button add_new. I want to make textentrydialog somewthing like this
 [Python, Using wxPython to get multiple input from user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796950/python-using-wxpython-to-get-multiple-input-from-user/42807355#42807355)

How can i do that? Do i need to just paste that code in ` def OnAddNew(self, event): 
Here is the pastebin link to my code: https://pastebin.com/UEYscgFa
I have created class inside a function, so is it possible to do in that way?

Comment: Remember! you can only accept one answer, not two!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO!
`GetData` is a class in its own right.
That code already provides you with the method.
The `MyFrame` is all fluff, to create a standalone working example.

```
def OnButton(self,event):
    dlg = GetData(parent = self.panel) 
    dlg.ShowModal()
    if dlg.result_name:
        self.log.AppendText("Name: "+dlg.result_name+"\n")
        self.log.AppendText("Surname: "+dlg.result_surname+"\n")
        self.log.AppendText("Nickname: "+dlg.result_nickname+"\n")
    else:
        self.log.AppendText("No Input found\n")
    dlg.Destroy()
```

Edit: I don't understand where the instructions in my comments eluded you but for my sins, here is your code cleaned up and edited as in the comments.

```
import sqlite3
import wx
import os

class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(1000,800))
        self.inter_list = list()
        self.plot_list = list()
        self.InitUI()
        self.Layout()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.p = wx.Panel(self)
        bs = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        gs = wx.GridSizer(10, 18, 5, 5)
        bs.Add(gs, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.search_btn=wx.Button(self.p,-1,"Search!")
        self.search_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnSearch, self.search_btn)
        bs.Add(self.search_btn,0,wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.p.SetSizer(bs)

    def OnSearch(self, event):
        dlg = GetData(parent = self.p)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        if dlg.result_name:
            print "Name: "+dlg.result_name+"\n"
            print "Surname: "+dlg.result_surname+"\n"
            print "Nickname: "+dlg.result_nickname+"\n"
        else:
            print "No Input found\n"
        dlg.Destroy()

class GetData(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, "Name Input", size= (650,220))
        self.p = wx.Panel(self,wx.ID_ANY)
        self.lblname = wx.StaticText(self.p, label="Name", pos=(20,20))
        self.name = wx.TextCtrl(self.p, value="", pos=(110,20), size=(500,-1))
        self.lblsur = wx.StaticText(self.p, label="Surname", pos=(20,60))
        self.surname = wx.TextCtrl(self.p, value="", pos=(110,60), size=(500,-1))
        self.lblnick = wx.StaticText(self.p, label="Nickname", pos=(20,100))
        self.nickname = wx.TextCtrl(self.p, value="", pos=(110,100), size=(500,-1))
        self.saveButton =wx.Button(self.p, label="Save", pos=(110,160))
        self.closeButton =wx.Button(self.p, label="Cancel", pos=(210,160))
        self.saveButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.SaveConnString)
        self.closeButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnQuit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnQuit)
        self.Show()

    def OnQuit(self, event):
        self.result_name = None
        self.Destroy()

    def SaveConnString(self, event):
        self.result_name = self.name.GetValue()
        self.result_surname = self.surname.GetValue()
        self.result_nickname = self.nickname.GetValue()
        self.Destroy()

app = wx.App()
Example(None, title = 'Raman Spectroscopy Database')
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: that gives me error: NameError: global name 'GetData' is not defined,        i want to make that same textentrydialog and finally i will send that text to use in my sqlite query

Comment: you can see my code here: https://github.com/svnitHIMANSHU/Raman-spectroscopy-database/blob/master/RAMAN.py

Comment: 1. Where is the `GetData` class you have omitted it from your code entirely and 2. You called your panel `p` so the call should be `dlg = GetData(parent = self.p)` and to achieve that you need to change all references to `p` to be `self.p` or perhaps something a little more descriptive.

Comment: can i create that GetData class inside OnButton function?

Comment: It says global name p is not defibned

Comment: I specifically addressed that issue in my previous comment. I suspect that you still have `p = wx.Panel(self)` in your code, which I warned you, would have to be altered to `self.p = wx.Panel(self)`

Comment: No! You can see here:  https://pastebin.com/mfqdp9Bs     i have changed it, and this gives me error: NameError: global name 'p' is not defined in line no. 26

Comment: Yes,Yes you have to change All references of `p` to `self.p` including `self.search_btn=wx.Button(p,-1,"Search!")` and `p.SetSizer(bs)` plus your have no `self.log` defined so you will have to change the references to `self.log.AppendText` to print commands.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147805/discussion-between-ts-vilasini-and-rolf-of-saxony).